# How to determine temporal prepositions

Tags: parts-of-speech, prepositions

I have several phrases in my text such as

**'The changes are consistent with *post* radiotherapy phrases'**

I would like to pick these sentences up

Is there a way of using parts of speech to determine temporal prepositions specifically eg a tag pattern?

Comment: At least one example you give ('previous EMR') isn't a preposition.

Comment: OK. Sorry. I've corrected it

Comment: In your example, "post" is not a preposition but a prefix, though it does of course have a temporal meaning. Thus the word should be hyphenated "post-radiotherapy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Part of speech tags can not be used to determine temporal prepositions.

**Long Answer:** If you **really** want to do this, extract the prepositional phrases, and run those phrases through 'prepositional sense disambiguation' system. They will use a combination of the preposition plus the object of the preposition to determine if the PP was indeed being used to indicate a temporal notion.

UPDATE: Also see the book, "Neural Networks for Natural Language Processing" by Yoav Goldberg. Chapter 7.6 walks the reader through the detailed steps of preposition sense disambiguation.

Comment: But .... "post" is not a preposition but a prefix, so "post-radiotherapy" is a single word, not a prep+noun syntactic construction.

Comment: Lexicographers don't agree on this one. See 4th PoS, https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/post  IMHO, it sure works like a preposition, "The food will be ready post 5pm." (after). One might argue that 'post' is a prefix to '5pm', but it seems cleaner as a preposition.

Comment: It may work like one, but the fact is that it isn't one. It only has noun and verb forms. I would hyphenate post-5pm, just like its opposite "pre-5pm", where "pre" is clearly a prefix, not a prep. By contrast "after" occurs as a temporal preposition in compounds such as "afternoon" "after-care", "after-thought" and the like. Btw, I think the Oxford is wrong -- in the example it gives, "post" is used incorrectly.

Comment: Oxford also recognizes 'pre' as a preposition. Of the 11,000 "event words" that semantically could use the 'post' prefix, dictionaries recognize only 100 - 700 as lexical items. Interesting to note, the dictionaries that don't recognize 'post' as a preposition, also don't recognize the hyphenated entry, leaving us with 10,000+ neologisms.

Comment: And it gets that wrong too! Pre-1700 is clearly a compound word, not a syntactic construction. Which is precisely why dictionaries are only good for meanings and simple spellings! Compare also "antenatal" -- no one would treat "ante" as a prep, so why would we want to say that "pre" is a prep?

Comment: I agree - liberties can be taken with hyphens (pre-1701, pre-1702, pre-1703, ...)  If  'pre' and 'post' can be attached to any number, and those constructions represent a compound word, than there would be an infinite number of compound words. By treating the prefix as a preposition, you avoid the 'infinite compound word' dilemma. Great quote: "Hyphenation in English is subject to fashion and arbitrary prescription, some of which may appear to give differences between national varieties."